# PHP : sorting a multidimensionnal array with a non-constant number of keys

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

In PHP, I have this kind of array (sorry for the big example, but it's a specific sort) :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 2
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 3
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 2
        [content] => 10
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 2
        [content] => 11
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 3
        [content] => 9
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 2
        [content] => 10
        [tag] => 'foo'
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 2
        [content] => 10
        [tag] => 'bar'
    )
```

And I want this output :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 2
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 2
        [content] => 10
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 2
        [content] => 10
        [tag] => 'bar'
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 2
        [content] => 10
        [tag] => 'foo'
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 2
        [content] => 11
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 3
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [title] => 1
        [desc] => 3
        [content] => 9
    )
```

And unfortunetly, `array_multisort()` can't sort arrays with a non-constant number of keys : it just ignore the all array ...
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sort for the sample code :

```
function cmp ($a, $b) {
  if ($a['desc'] == $b['desc']) {
    if (!isset($a['content']) && !isset($b['content'])) {
      return 0;
    }
    else if (!isset($a['content'])) {
      return -1;
    }
    else if (!isset($b['content'])) {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
      if ($a['content'] == $b['content']) {
        if (!isset($a['tag'])) {
          return -1;
        }
        else if (!isset($b['tag'])) {
          return 1;
        }
        else {
          if ($a['tag'] == $b['tag']) {
            return 0;
          }
          else if ($a['tag'] < $b['tag']) {
            return -1;
          }
          else {
            return 1;
          }
        }
        return 0;
      }
      else if ($a['content'] < $b['content']) {
        return -1;
      }
      else {
        return 1;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
  else if ($a['desc'] < $b['desc']) {
    return -1;
  }
  else {
    return 1;
  }
}
usort($array, 'cmp');
```

Thanks to **@Nelson, @therefromhere, and @xdazz** to put me on `usort()` :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me exactly what criteria you want to order by, but you can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), you provide it a function that defines the comparison.

Comment: In fact, the sort is a loop on each key, in a numerical order. I guess I can rebuild the array with a lot of loop ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `usort` with a tailored `cmp` function for your special needs, like the following code:

```
usort($arr, "cmp");

function cmp($a, $b) {
    $array = array('title','desc','content','tag');
    foreach ($array as &$ar) {
        $ai = isset($a[$ar]);
        $bi = isset($b[$ar]);
        if ($ai && !$bi) {
            return 1;
        }
        if ($bi && !$ai) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (!$bi) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ($a[$ar] > $b[$ar]) {
            return 1;
        }
        if ($b[$ar] > $a[$ar]) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

that should do what you want.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I just did on my side too ! Perfect :)

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, my code seems more concise and readable that your version so you may want consider it as an alternative approach to compare on. Remember to upvote any answers you deem useful and ACCEPT any answer you want (could be your answer too).